# Start path relative to corner of image

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have written the following script which uses the ImageMagick* `convert` utility to append axis labels to an existing image.

```
LEFT_="l -30,0 +2,+2  -6,-2 +6,-2  -2,+2 z"
RIGHT_="l 30,0 -2,+2  +6,-2 -6,-2  +2,+2 z"
convert -size 240x160 pattern:SMALLFISHSCALES \
  -pointsize 16 -fill black -background white \
  -gravity SouthEast -splice 0x20 \
  -draw "translate 40,0 text 0,0 'Time' stroke red path 'm 5,2 $RIGHT_'" \
  -gravity NorthWest -splice 20x0 \
  -draw "rotate +90 translate 40,-10 text 0,0 'Value' path 'm -5,2 $LEFT_'" \
  example.png
```

Which produces the following image:

[image: convert command output]

This is almost exactly what I am after, except that the red arrow is out of place. I expected the red arrow to appear next to the `Time` label, since its start point is specified as a relative position in the same draw command.  Unfortunately, it looks like the `-gravity` option is affecting the `text` primitive, but not the `path` primitive.

Is there a way to reference the SouthEast corner, or the `Time` text label when specifying the start position of the red arrow? I can't use absolute coordinates, because the size of the image varies.

*ImageMagick 6.7.8-9 on CentOS 7

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Answer**

Maybe you can make Unicode text arrows like this then they will be affected by gravity...

```
perl -e 'binmode(STDOUT,":utf8"); print "Time ... \x{2192}\x{2191}";'|
     convert -font TimesNewRoman -pointsize 36 label:@- arrows.png
```

[image]

Depending on your OS, the following may do as a replacement for the Perl above...

```
printf "%b" "\u2192" | convert ...
```

**Original Answer**

I am not at all familiar with paths, but I can suggest a way to achieve what you want that doesn't use gravity at all, and maybe that will help.

Rather than use `-splice`, you can clone your original image and crop it to the size you planned to splice on, and then `-append` the strips that label the axes. It is easier to show you the command than explain it!

```
convert -size 240x160 pattern:SMALLFISHSCALES            \
   \( +clone -crop x20+0+0 -fill blue -colorize 100% \)  \
  -append                                                \
  \( +clone -crop 20x+0+0 -fill red -colorize 100% \)    \
  +swap +append result.png
```

I have filled the x-axis blue, but remove that and add whatever labelling and arrows you need, and I filled the y-axis red, but likewise remove that and add labelling and arrows - rotating as necessary.

Two tricky things to note...

`-append` will append the second image *below* the first

`+append` will append the second image *to the right* of the first, so I `+swap` beforehand to put it on the left side.

[image]

Comment: Unless I am missing something, this still leaves me with the same problem.  How do I draw an arrow at the right edge of the blue box if I don't know beforehand how wide the image will be?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. I thought the gravity you were using to splice was affecting the gravity you wanted to use for your paths so I foolishly made a way to avoid gravity and splicing :-) Anyway, I have had another attempt now...